# Installing Gnome on FreeBSD

Tags: gnome, compiling, freebsd, software-installation

I am trying to install Gnome on a freshly installed FreeBSD using the ports.

I am stuck with an error message that says:
`Checking for headers required to compile python extensions ... not found`
Then it fails unexpectedly.

I've tried to re-install python27 and that didn't help.

What could possibly be the problem?

**EDIT:**

I am running FreeBSD 9.1; I tried to install gnome by following the [FAQ](http://www.freebsd.org/gnome/docs/faq2.html#q1)
I simply 
`cd /usr/ports/x11/gnome2` then I ran `make install clean`and as for the configs, I left them unchanged; by checking `make config` I have two unselected options:
`XSCREENSAVER` 
`MAPI`

As for the output of `python2.7-config --includes` I got the following:
`-I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/python2.7`

Comment: Which port are you using? (e.g. latest port tree, portsnapped today, from where, e.g. /usr/ports/devel/gnome-common/ ) Which options have been set (e.g. run `make config`). Which FreeBSD version? What is the output of `python2.7-config --includes` ? ...

Comment: Excuse me for the lack information, please check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as the error noted was that 'make' was looking for the `pth` file.
I fixed it by 
`cp /usr/local/include/pth /usr/local/include/python2.7`
 I have python2.7 installed instead of 2.6

Of course this is a work-around and not a serious solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing header files necessary for compilation of Python extensions which are Gnome dependency. That should not happen if you were following handbook and use stable branch. You do not really provide enough information to troubleshoot
the problem.

Comment: I tried to follow the FAQ, not the handbook, you're right. I've edited my post to include more information; kindly check it out.